# Buggy texture coordinate mapping

Tags: glsl, glsles

I can't find the issue with my offset to coordinate and vice versa mapping however there's a problem that manifests itself very repeatedly as soon as the sizes get slightly large. This runs on Chrome.

I am trying a 55x56 texture and I use the following routines to map from a logical interger offset to the uv (st) of TexCoords and back. Somehere some error gets accumulated causing two subsequent offset (eg. 54 and 55) to map to the same texel.

The line for halfTexel addition below was found in one of StackOverflow posts (and it makes very much sense). At the beginning of my shader i also have this line:

```
// const vec2 halfTexel = vec2(${1.0 / (2.0 * xScale)}, ${1.0 / (2.0 * yScale)});
// xscale is the width (55)
// yscale is the height (56)

precision highp float;
...
vec2 offsetToCoords_A(int offset) {
  const vec2 halfTexel = vec2(0.00909090909090909, 0.008928571428571428);
  const float xScale = 55.0;
  const float yScale = 56.0;
  float offsetF = float(offset);
  float s = mod(offsetF, 55.0);
  float t = floor(offsetF / 55.0);
  vec2 coords = vec2(s/xScale, t/yScale) + halfTexel;
  return coords;
}

int coordsToOffset_A(vec2 coords) {
  const float xScale = 55.0;
  const float yScale = 56.0;
  float s = coords.s * xScale;
  float t = coords.t * yScale;
  int offset = int(t) * 55 + int(s);
  return offset;
}
```

sample result:

```
49,50,51,52,53,54,54,56,57,58,59,
...
106,107,108,109,109,111,112,113
```

Comment: How exactly is the sample result obtained? It looks like the output of `coordsToOffset_A`, but what is its input? Is the function `offsetToCoords_A` used in any way?

Comment: If I take an offset say 55 and pass it to ```offsetToCoords_A``` I'd get coordinates which i could use to pass to texture2D(A,coords)```.
What I'm also showing is the other function which is I use to map from the varying (TexCoords) to an offset. I think that function ```coordsToOffset``` is ok. Between these two calls there is some processing of course. However I have narrowed the problem to these two.

Comment: I just printed the ```.s``` result of calls to  ```offsetToCoords_A```. O the 55th call, the resulting vec2 has 1.0090909004211426 as its x coordinate. That shows a problem with the ```mod``` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed the mod and changed `offsetToCoords` to the following:

```
vec2 offsetToCoords_A(int offset) {
  const vec2 halfTexel = vec2(0.00909090909090909, 0.008928571428571428);
  const float xScale = 55.0;
  const float yScale = 56.0;
  int t = offset / int(xScale);
  int s = offset - t*int(xScale);
  vec2 coords = vec2(s,t)/vec2(xScale, yScale) + halfTexel;
  return coords;
}
```